# Unable to execute TestNG.xml using Jenkins for code committed in git repo

Tags: git, jenkins, testng

I am trying to execute my Selenium project code through Jenkins using TestNG.xml. I am able to successfully run the code through Jenkins using maven, but now I want to setup the build so that I can run the same using testNG.xml file. For that

1. I setup the New item in jenkins as a Freestyle project (even though my project is a maven project).
2. I added a batch file to my project with content below

java org.testng.TestNG testngscripts.xml
pause

The testng jars are in my mvn dependencies folder. But I think since I create as freelance project, it did not get read and I get following error on jenkins after executing build.

```
*> git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/uppalvishal/SeleniumMockProject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 703b73fd5b9fde5404b52d2caa3f8c4769554291 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 703b73fd5b9fde5404b52d2caa3f8c4769554291 # timeout=10
Commit message: "committed batch file"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Selenium_Automation_TestNG] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\vuppal\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins2717609267405812765.bat
C:\Users\vuppal\.jenkins\workspace\Selenium_Automation_TestNG>testngBatchFile.bat
**C:\Users\vuppal\.jenkins\workspace\Selenium_Automation_TestNG>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG**
C:\Users\vuppal\.jenkins\workspace\Selenium_Automation_TestNG>pause
Press any key to continue . . . 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE*
```

I have even tried putting the testng jars by creating a lib folder in my project and changing batch file to

java -cp lib* org.testng.TestNG testngscripts.xml
pause

and also the complete path to lib folder in github code like

java -cp  https://github.com/uppalvishal/SeleniumMockProject/tree/master/lib org.testng.TestNG testngscripts.xml

My question is how do I get this class org.testng.TestNG in my classpath so that Jenkins can execute my testNG xml file

Answer (score 0):

Is TestNG Jar present in pom.xml? Are you using maven?

You need to use maven for this.
Put your TestNG jar dependency in maven and upload on GIT
Once you download the project from  GIT, the maven will automatically download TestNG jar.
It works fine this way

Comment: Yes Rahul, TestNG.xml is present and testNG dependency added to pom.xml. My issue is I am able to execute this project as a maven project through Jenkins but that uses mvn test. How can I run this project as a testNG project and get testNG report through jenkins. I read up and it seems we need to specify a batch file which would execute the testNG.xml file. But what path do I give in the batch file . Thanks for your response